# More filters for candidate search: reputation, open-source projects, blog, certifications

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I've had a profile on Careers 2.0 for a while and have started considering using it for recruitment. At this point I have only tried it without a subscription so pardon me if these features are available to subscribers.

Having applied the basic filters I still have 8.5k candidates to go through.
It would be useful to be able to narrow down this search with some of the following criteria:

- Users having more than X reputation, or users in top X% of given technology, or ability to sort by reputation
- Users having blogs (or other publications, I suppose that would mean any entry in the Writing section)
- Users having open-source projects
- Users having certifications in given technologies